# Meteor cluster, can I use IP address instead of sub domain for balancers?

Tags: meteor, cluster-computing

From the [readme](https://github.com/meteorhacks/cluster):

```
Making your instance a Balancer is pretty simple. Just export the following environment variable.

export CLUSTER_BALANCER_URL=https://subdomain1.domainname.com
export CLUSTER_BALANCER_URL=https://subdomain2.domainname.com
```

Can I use ip instead?

```
server1: export CLUSTER_BALANCER_URL=https://server1_ip
server2: export CLUSTER_BALANCER_URL=https://server2_ip
```

Comment: Did you try?  Was there an error?

Comment: I tried, there is no error, not sure is it the best way to use it.